# How to make an argument of the method, the array and hash,simultaneously

Tags: ruby

I need send in method argument which is array and hash simultaneously. But don't know, how. Here is example:

```
def method(here should be this argument)
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by simultaneously? That the object can be either types?

Answer (score 0):

```
def show(*a)
 p a
 if a.length.even? == true
  p Hash[*a]
 else
  p "hash conversion not possible"
 end
end

show(1,2,3,4)
show(1,2,3)
```

*output:*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
{1=>2, 3=>4}

[1, 2, 3]
"hash conversion not possible"
```

**EDIT:**

From comment of OP here is the code OP could use:

```
 def add(*arg)
   @entries = {}
   arg.each_slice(2) do |a| @entries[a.first] = a.last end
   p @entries
 end

 add(1,2,3,4)
```

*Output:*

```
{1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Comment: Hello. I use "each" for this argument and get error. How use "each" only for array? how check argument ?

Comment: here is my code:
    def add(defs)
    defs.each do |word, definition|
    @entries[word] = definition
    end
    end

Comment: @JohnOggy `each` can take only one argument.